# Force insert in paper trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

Is it possible to force an insert in paper trail table 'versions' without making the insert in the real table. I need to store a 'create' insert in the paper trails table so I can get the object after a confirmation, and just then, make the real insert.

Thanks

Comment: i don't understand what you are asking for. does how would that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

PaperTrail::Versions are just ActiveRecord objects, so you can instantiate and save them just like any of your models:

```
version = PaperTrail::Version.new
version.item = my_item
version.object = my_item
version.event = :create
version.save!
```

PaperTrail cannot store unsaved objects in its `object` column, however - it gets saved as nil. This means that `.object` will be `nil` if you load this version record out of the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When using your code I am getting "1" in the object column. Is there any way to save as it should be?